# how can i hide previous label in will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I can hide page links but i can't hide previous label. Any idea? Thanks.

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :page_links => false %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it looks like you can set the label using `:previous_label`, I don't think you can disable it.

A workaround would be to add a CSS rule to not display the previous link.

```
span.prev_page, a.prev_page {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot disable the previous label, the best workaround is to use the following:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :page_links => false, :previous_label => '' %>
```